# I'm trying to produce a line of code the returns the score of a word but at the moment I am getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, nameerror

```
def getWordScore(word):
    points_total = 0 
for letter in word:
      points_total += getLetterScore.get(letter,0)
return points_total
brownie_points = getWordScore("BROWNIE")
```

> output NameError: name 'word' is not defined

I'm a bit confused at why I'm getting the nameError,Any suggestions?

Comment: please fix the indentations, I've edited it to show what you have pasted. You're probably actually just in need of indenting some things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a proper indentation should do the trick

```
    def getWordScore(word):
        points_total = 0
        for letter in word:
            points_total += getLetterScore.get(letter, 0)
        return points_total
brownie_points = getWordScore("BROWNIE")
```

do notice that you have not provided `getLetterScore`, so there might be some other issues

Comment: Great, Solved the nameError issue!!